# Windows form application replaces each time the exported excel

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, localdb

I have wrote the following code for exporting my local database data to an excel file. The fact is that it is working properly, but I'd only like to export it with the actual date, or just month, like august, or something like that. Besides that, the problem that really matters is that it replaces every time the previously exported excel file. How can I change this thing? Thanks !

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             var connString = (@"Data Source=" + System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)) + @"\Angajati.sdf");
            using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(connString))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    var query = "SELECT * FROM info ";
                    var command = new SqlCeCommand(query, conn);
                    var dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(command);
                    var dataTable = new DataTable();
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }

            }

            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            Int16 i, j;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 2; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1[j, i].Value.ToString();
                }
            }

            //adds column names to excel
            string[] colNames = new string[dataGridView1.Columns.Count];
            int col = 0;

            foreach (DataGridViewColumn dc in dataGridView1.Columns)
                colNames[col++] = dc.HeaderText;

            char lastColumn = (char)(65 + dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1);

            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").Value2 = colNames;
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").Font.Bold = true;
            xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").VerticalAlignment
                        = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\Andrei\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Stellwag\Stellwag\db.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);
            MessageBox.Show("Salvat cu succes");
        }



        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you don't want `db.xls` replaced every time, I suggest you use a different name on each save. Maybe something derived from the current date/time?

Comment: Do you mean you want to filter the report to specific date period? Modify the query in var query = "SELECT * FROM info ";

Comment: do you mean you want to update certain content of file, not the whole file?

Comment: No. I would like not to replace each time. To have separate files every time I press the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want it to overwrite the same workbook every time then you'll need to specify a different file name rather than hard coding it in.

Something simple like creating the filename with the current datetime would normally be sufficient (you can change the format to suit you):

```
string fileName = @"db " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss") + @".xls";
string filePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Andrei\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Stellwag\Stellwag", fileName);

xlWorkBook.SaveAs(filePath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
```

This would produce a file like this:

> db 01-09-2015 10-32-35.xls

There is still not explicit check to see if the file exists, but unless you're clicking it every second it's unlikely to overwrite.

Comment: It's because I'm an idiot who put `:` in a filename, changed to `-`. Also changed `XLSX` to `XLS`. Try now ;-)

Comment: Solved it. Works like charm. There was a problem with path too. Thanks a lot sir !

Comment: Glad I can help, no problem! :-)